# Можно ли ограничить количество записей в таблице?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Можно ли в SQLite ограничить размер таблицы на количество записей и как это организовать? 
Например таблица набирает суммарно 100 строк, после чего самые старые записи  удаляются и записываются новые.

Comment: А для какой цели такое нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать триггер на вставку новых записей в таблицу.
Предположим, у вас имеется таблица `_table` с полями

- `_id`(ключ какой-то)
- `_time`(время создания записи)

Тогда триггер будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_till_50 INSERT ON _table WHEN (select count(*) from _table)>100 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM _table WHERE _table._id IN  (SELECT _table._id FROM _table ORDER BY _table._time  limit (select count(*) - 100 from _table ));
END;
```

При вставке новой записи самые старые записи будут удаляться. В базе всегда будет не более 100 записей.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, количество записей ограничить невозможно, но есть один трюк, который может помочь:

- Создать таблицу
- Заполнить её сотней записей, каждая из которых на одну миллисекунду старше предыдущей
- Вместо операции вставки выполнить операцию обновления для самой старой записи

Answer (score -3):

Стек FILO предназначен именно для этого.
Как его реализовать с конкретными объектами - дело техники.
Но понять, отразить это в мозгу - просто необходимо...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
.